# Can you use Yammer REST API to merge Yammer accounts

Tags: javascript, rest, yammer

At the moment I use a CSV file which holds the old and new email addresses and then use bulk upload to merge yammer accounts.

Is it possible to use an api to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge with Bulk Update, but you are probably changing email addresses. There isn't a way to do this with the REST API, and eventually Bulk Update inside Yammer will no longer be required when all users are using O365 identity and being managed by Azure AD.

Comment: Hi,
Our users are already using Azure AD, but sometimes they have more than one profile which we merge with the bulk update, which like you say is probably swapping email addresses and deleting old accounts. Just thought there would be a way to do it with javascript.